# Is there anyway to carry a value in php forward to a second page?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have created a php site, and previously it was listing only products with defined values. I have now changed it to include an array of products for example all products WHERE id = "spotlights"

and this works great so it means I can add new products just to the database, but I still have to add the second page manually. e.g going from the product div on the main page, through to www.example.com/spotlight_1.php

Is there anyway in PHP to carry the data from my index.php e.g. the ID through to the next page? so that I can have a template product.php page, and I can use a database pull to echo the product information required.

So on index.php i click on the product with ID="1" and on the product.php page, it loads the relevant data for product 1.

I can write the php SQL/mySQL calls myself, its just the way to carry accross a value from the previous page which I dont understand

Regards

Henry

**p.s.** 
all the IDs and things are stored in the database already as 1 to 3digit values e.g. 3 or or 93 or 254

Any advice as always is greatly appreciated

Regards

Henry

Comment: Sounds like you want to use sessions: http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

im not sure if im understading this correctly but you can pass the variable from one page to another using GET variables, or in other words, using the query string in the URL.

So, in index.php you will have links like this:

```
<a href="product.php?p=1">Product 1</a>
```

In the second page (product.php) you can get this variable using this code:

```
$product_id = $_GET['p'];
```

And then query your database like this:

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '" . $product_id . "'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp

Note: Be careful with the way you query your database, the previous code is only a demonstration of how to retrieve the info, but is not a secure solution. I recommend you to check PDO (http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Yea I heard using a mysql_ lookup is now considered "Dangerous" and that a mysqli_ or PDO_ lookup is better? Can anybody explain why?

Comment: is there anyway to run a $query variable from a GET like this? for example, I have the page index.php, and then it displays 3 types of products, `index.php?type=1` , `index.php?type=2` and `index.php?type=3`

then on the `index.php` page, id like to have `$product_type = $_GET['type'];` and then run the following query `$query = 
"SELECT * FROM $usertable WHERE tabID LIKE '%$product_type%'";` is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use GET if you do not care other users to see your variables, or you can use POST to not let the users what your variables are (useful for password submissions)

One thing to mention is that if you use GET (url?key=value) you need to encode the value using PHP's utf8 enconde function, if you use POST, you don't have to worry about this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways.  You can put the data into session variables, you can POST the data to the 2nd page or pass the data via GET as URL parameters, or you can even save the data in a browser cookie.

Which approach you might use will likely depend on the security requirements for the data and whether you want to be able to access that data strictly via URL (in case of URL parameters).

Answer (score 0):

You can either keep passing the value forward in the request scope until you no longer need it (commonly passed in the url ?var=value), or you can also use sessions if this needs to live longer than the request scope.